# Set value of a column on a row back to NULL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small table with rows and columns

```
<tr>
    <td>Warranty</td>
    <td><?php echo ($admrmadetrow['rd_warranty'] == 1 ? "YES" : ' '); ?></td>
    <td><select name="rd_warranty" data-placeholder="rd_warranty" class="form-control">
            <option></option>
            <option value="1">YES</option>
            <option value="0">NO</option>
          </select></td>
</tr>
```

first column shows is just a name, second column is the value from out of my mysql table and last column you can choose a value Yes(1) and No(0) and on submit of a form it has to update the mysql table and the second column with the new value except if the select did not changed `<option></option>`.

My problem i am facing is when the second column is `Yes` and it has to change to `No` it doesn't update . I know `0` is the same as `NULL` but how can you manage this problem and change `1` to `0`

I don't get any error it submits but stays at Yes(1).

Could someone help me with this?

Edit:

This is my code to update my database

```
foreach (array_filter($_POST) as $key => $value){

    $update_rma_detail_stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE rma_detail SET $key = ? WHERE r_nr = ? AND rd_artikel_code = ?");
    $update_rma_detail_stmt->bindParam(1, $value);
    $update_rma_detail_stmt->bindParam(2, $getadmrmaid);
    $update_rma_detail_stmt->bindParam(3, $artcode);
    $update_rma_detail_stmt->execute();


}
```

Comment: need to see your code that updated the db

Comment: 0 is NOT the same as null. Nothing is the "same as null" including null itself.

Comment: You're right Marc but still i think that this mysql update is dropping this because it cannot update a empty field (0) and because of that it doesn't do anything. If i change the 0 to 9 for example it works but i just want to get the value of the column in my mysql back to NULL like it is in the beginning if there was never a value. In other words just clear the specific column in a specific row in my table

Comment: **WARNING**: Don't allow arbitrary user variables from `$_POST` into your queries. What you're doing here with `$key` is extremely dangerous. Always properly escape these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If field value is empty in HTML code, your POST request will be generated with empty string value(like '').
To set NULL in prepared statement you must use bindValue function, your code will be like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){

$update_rma_detail_stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE rma_detail SET $key = ? WHERE r_nr = ? AND rd_artikel_code = ?");
/*you can use "empty($value)" or "$value==''" condition*/
if(empty($value)){
    $update_rma_detail_stmt->bindValue(1, null);
}else{
    $update_rma_detail_stmt->bindParam(1, $value);
}
$update_rma_detail_stmt->bindParam(2, $getadmrmaid);
$update_rma_detail_stmt->bindParam(3, $artcode);
```

}
$update_rma_detail_stmt->execute();

Comment: Worked but for the best i just used value 9 for No so it updates to. This will help me better further in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE in the update since you basically need NULL to be updated when 0 is selected. Something like

```
$update_rma_detail_stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE rma_detail SET $key = CASE WHEN ? = 0 then NULL else ? END WHERE r_nr = ? AND rd_artikel_code = ?");
```

Note: the answer here is using CASE statement, I am not sure 100% of the code above since you are using placeholders (?)  for values and I am not very familiar with this.

For more details regarding CASE please visit: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Answer (score 0):

On `select` into mysql, use `IFNULL(rd_warranty,0)` best pratice!